# Can't figure out why my str2Int function is returning 0

Tags: c++

The output of the following code is 0. I can't figure out why. (I know I already asked a question about a compiler error in this block of code. Now it's running but not working properly.)

Anyone have an idea? Or have a better way of writing my str2Int function? It's supposed to take a string like "2833812" and convert it to the int 2833812.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>

const char digit_ints[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
std::map<char,int> digit_map; 


int str2Int(const std::string& S) { 
    int sz(S.size()), sum(0);
    if (sz == 0) { 
        std::cout << "str2Int() cannot take an empty string as a parameter." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } else { 
        int sum(0);
        for (int j(0), k(sz - 1); j < sz; ++j, --k) { 
            if ((S[j]) < '0' || (S[j]) > '9') { 
                std::cout << "str2Int can only take strings with chars '0' through '9' as parameters." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            } else { 
                sum += digit_map[S[j]] * (int)pow(10.0, k);
            }
        }

    }
    return sum;
} 


int main() { 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)  
    digit_map.insert(std::pair<char,int>(digit_ints[i], i));


    std::cout << str2Int("3421");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those global `map`s are extremely ugly and superfluous, and `(int)pow(10.0, k);` is the worst possible way to compute 10 to an integer power. And `#include <math.h>` is deprecated, you're looking for `#include <cmath>`.

Comment: Now it is fixed. Ask for a code review. codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line

```
int sum(0);
```

From the else block, you are creating a new sum variable which is scoped to the else block which is "hiding" the sum variable from the outer scope. You are returning the sum variable from the outer scope.

Comment: Any explanation as to why?

Comment: Besides possible improvements (in the OP code) - the right answer!

Answer (score 3):

Credit goes to Chris Taylor, but I just want to explain why `int sum(0);` is wrong in the `else` branch: you are declaring **another** `sum` variable in the inner block, so that shadows (hides) the one you are returning later.

A better way to write your function would be (without error checking):

```
int str2int(const std::string &s)
{
    // do error checking, then:
    int i = 0;
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end()) {
        i *= 10;
        i += *it++ - '0';
    }

    return i;
}
```

**Why is this better than your current approach?**

- It avoids global variables;
- It doesn't rely on `pow()` providing an exact result (which it doesn't). Generally, when working with integers, you should never use functions that operate on floating-point numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `i += *it++ - '0';` before `i *= 10;`?

Comment: @Smac89 Exactly, I shouldn't.

Comment: Ok, but the reason is not immediately obvious which is why I asked

Comment: @Smac89 Hmm... arguably. Just think about it for a moment, and it will be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

> Or have a better way of writing my str2Int function?

If you're using C++11:

```
#include <string>

int str2Int(const std::string& str)
{
    return std::stoi(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or have a better way of writing my str2Int function?

```
int str2Int(std::string const& str) {
  istringstream is(str);
  int ret;
  is >> ret;
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: For that matter, just [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: @JohannGerell Not if it's an exercise (you know, people learning programming at school sometimes get homework).

Comment: @JohannGerell Then why not `std::strtoi()`? This smells very, very suspiciously like homework. (Out of the school world, everyone uses the stdlib for basic tasks like this, so if one has to write a "convert string to integer" function, ...)

Comment: @H2CO3: ‘strtol‘ gives maximum flexibility. ‘std::stoi‘ gives ease of use. For someone asking how to write the conversion himself, I suggest the latter. For someone asking if ‘std::stoi‘ is maybe not enough, I suggest the former.

Comment: @JohannGerell I wasn't asking "why `strtol()`?", because I use that function all the time and I love it. I was really asking "why `stringstream` (when we can have `stoi()` and `strtol()`)?"...

Comment: @H2CO3: I upped SoapBox's suggestion for std::stoi, what do you refer to with stringstream?

Comment: @JohannGerell This answer suggests the use of `std::istringstream` for doing the conversion.

Comment: @H2CO3: Well, my upping didn't. Are you saying '@'-references are incomprehensible?

Comment: @JohannGerell No. I was referring to your very first comment ("+infinity") here, to which I replied "not if it's an exercise".

Comment: @H2CO3: I upped std::stoi, didn't I?

Comment: @JohannGerell You did. I was trying to explain that using an stdlib function may not be the solution if OP's task is to implement the conversion algorithm on his own.